# PSD to PNG conversion, showing black screen

Tags: imagemagick, png, watermark, psd

PSD to PNG conversion, output image as black screen.

Sample PSD file
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/axj0p5cpl6pxx0n/DXL_SP21_F2219_P_23_202.psd?dl=0]

PSD to png conversion code: convert sample.psd[0] output.png

Comment: Sample psd file [https://www.dropbox.com/s/axj0p5cpl6pxx0n/DXL_SP21_F2219_P_23_202.psd?dl=0]

Comment: Works fine for me as in my answer below. What is your Imagemagick version and platform/OS?

Answer (score 0):

The conversion works fine for me on IM 6.9.12-58 Q16 Mac OSX Monterey

convert DXL_SP21_F2219_P_23_202.psd[0] x.png

[image]

(Resized by 50% to keep within 2 MB limit)

Comment: Thanks. but still i am getting same issue

Comment: Works fine for me as in my answer below. What is your Imagemagick version and platform/OS? Also what version of libpng? Do you have the PNG delegate showing in `convert -version` or `magick -version`

Comment: Imagemagick version 7.0 and MacOS Big Sur

Comment: With IM 7, use magick, not convert. Try `magick DXL_SP21_F2219_P_23_202.psd[0] x.png`. What is your exact version of Imagemagick 7?  What do you get from `magick -version`. Does it have PNG listed under delegates?